# Adding Firebase Cloud Messaing to Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: firebase, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project using Visual Studio 2015 that is going to be running on both iOS and Android. I'm currently working on implementing Remote Push Notifications and am having problems with the Android-based system.

I'm following the [FCM Notifications Walkthrough](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/) provided by Xamarin and it goes well up until the step where it says to "**Add the Google Services JSON File**". I can get the file from the Firebase Console and add it to the project, but once I set the Build Action to ***GoogleServicesJson***, that's where the problems begin.

After adding the file and setting the Build Action to the proper values, my project grinds to a halt. Before it would just take a minute to compile and deploy onto a test device, now it takes well over 5 minutes. I have tried closing and re-opening Visual Studio and while the project loads in the normal amount of time, it seems to just hang there for an extra few minutes.

I've gone through all steps of the walkthrough and have narrowed it down to when I change the Build Action, so I know for a fact that it has something to do with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work, although it's more of a workaround than an actual fix. I found [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/250165/#Comment_250165) that suggested turning the google-services.json file to a seperate Settings file and even provided a T4 Template to automatically convert the file to a seperate file.

Hopefully the actual reason why will be addressed by a future version at some point.